# How can I specify the filename, in addition to the path in fluentd?

Tags: fluentd

@type file
  path /var/log/mypath/
  compress gzip

Instead of the default naming "buffer.b59c4ab55c09fb9054da2a354fc47cad0.log", can I get fluentd to save into a customized file-name?

Answer (score 0):

```
@type file
path /var/log/mypath/file.${tag}.%Y%m%d
```

this will create a buffered file like this:

```
/var/log/mypath/file.${tag}.%Y%m%d.buffer.bajshdjkasdkjhajdks.log
```

and

```
/var/log/mypath/file.${tag}.%Y%m%d.buffer.bajshdjkasdkjhajdks.log.meta
```

After it is flushed (when timekey is used):

/var/log/mypath/file.test.20180405.log  (tag was test)

You could set timekey to 1d. Then everyday a new file will be created and the old one gets your naming.